# "Daily vote limit reached. Please go vote more!"

Tags: bug, voting

I just voted on an answer and got this:

[image]

> - Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 8 hours.
> - You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!

The idea of the message itself makes sense (putting aside the fact that by the very nature of the [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) site, you're bound to have way more answer votes than question votes anyway).

But it feels a little odd to be reprimanded for not doing something while being forbidden from doing it at the same time.

Could these messages be made mutually exclusive, or at least not shown at the same time if there's, say, more than an hour until the next UTC day when votes roll over? I get that the concept of the message still applies, but it does feel a bit... nagging. "You're out of votes. Come back tomorrow! Oh by the way, use them on questions too because you're not doing that enough! And remember that for 8 hours!"

Comment: I don't really think of them as bugs. One is telling you that you can't vote, the other is saying that you should vote on questions as well as answers. Seems straightforward to me.